# Xcode - Resize Buttons with Images Proportionally for iPhone 4s, 5, 6, 6+ in AutoLayout

Tags: iphone, xcode, resize, autolayout

I designed a UI that simply doesn't scale the right way - always squeezing and stretching something. I get everything to align the right way but the scaling messes everything up. In Subviews it even gets worse...

Here is a simplified version of the UI:
http:// i.imgur.com/VIKVm5y.png

All the grey circles have images inside, should be buttons and scale proportional to every iPhone display size - so that a bigger display gets bigger buttons...

It's only meant to be for iPhones and portrait mode only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok actually this was pretty simple and I feel kinda stupid I asked the question in the first place.
The solution was to lock the aspect ratio and set either the height or with equal to the superview and then edit the proportion to it in a second step until you have desired result...

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more please as I am a newbie and i'm finding it really confusing. thanks